# Configure cron to run URL every 15 minutes

Tags: php, centos, cron, centos6

I'd like to set up a cron job to go to a URL every 15 minutes. I have a VPS with centos 6 on it and access to SSH. This is what I have tried so far with no luck:

1. In ssh, type "crontab -e"
2. `* /15 * * * * wget (URL HERE)`
3. Hit 'ESC' and type ":wq" to save work and exit

I'm sure theres something wrong with the way I'm writting this out.

Comment: You may want to remove the space here: `* /15`. If that doesnt fix it, there take a look at the cron log files.

Comment: What does your `crontab -l` output?

Answer (score 4):

There should be no space between the range and the step.

```
*/15
```

Comment: The cron log files stored in /var/log/cron showed that the url was not working. Even after the space was removed, where exactly are the cronjobs saved after I do the :wq command? Could it be that its not in a php file